# Sum a numeric properties of leafs counting leafs only once despite multiple paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following setup:

- I have multiple repositories.
- A repository has many tags.
- A tag points to many blobs.
- Different tags can point to the same blob; hence, a blob can be referenced by many tags.
- A blob has the property *size_in_mb* which is a numeric value.

(If this sounds familiar, that is how a Docker registry stores data on disk.)

What do I want to achieve?

I want to have the sum of *size_in_mb* for each repository,
but count each blob only once despite the fact that it can be referenced
by many tags.

Let us see following example:

```
CREATE (b1:Blob {name:"b1", size_in_mb: 1000})
CREATE (b2:Blob {name: "b2", size_in_mb: 100})
CREATE (r1:Repository {name: 'r1'})
CREATE (r2:Repository {name: 'r2'})
CREATE (t1:Tag {name: 'r1:latest'})
CREATE (t2:Tag {name: 'r1:old'})
CREATE (t3:Tag {name: 'r2:latest'})
CREATE (t1)-[:TAG_OF]->(r1)
CREATE (t2)-[:TAG_OF]->(r1)
CREATE (t3)-[:TAG_OF]->(r2)
CREATE (b1)-[:TAGGED_BY]->(t1)
CREATE (b1)-[:TAGGED_BY]->(t2)
CREATE (b1)-[:TAGGED_BY]->(t3)
CREATE (b2)-[:TAGGED_BY]->(t2)
```

We have

```
MATCH(r:Repository)<--(t:Tag)<--(b:Blob)
RETURN r,t,b
```

[Graph Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6jRq.png)

A simple sum

```
MATCH(r:Repository)<--(t:Tag)<--(b:Blob)
RETURN r.name, sum(b.size_in_mb)
```

returns

```
r.name  sum(b.size_in_mb)
"r1"    2100
"r2"    1000
```

but want to have

```
r.name  sum(b.size_in_mb)
"r1"    1100
"r2"    1000
```

because blob b1 and b2 shold be only counted once for repository r1.

How should I phrase my Cypher query to reach that goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it, based on Michaels answer:

```
MATCH(r:Repository)<--(t:Tag)<--(b:Blob) 
with r, collect(distinct b) as distinctBlobs 
RETURN r.name,  reduce(totalSum = 0, n IN distinctBlobs | totalSum + n.size_in_mb) as size_sum
```

Not sure if this is the optimal solution but it does produce the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `WITH distinct r,b, collect(t) as tags` before you sum the blobs.

```
MATCH(r:Repository)<--(t:Tag)<--(b:Blob)
WITH distinct r,b, collect(distinct t) as tags
RETURN r.name, sum(b.size_in_mb), tags
```

Comment: The query it leads leads to the output (not sure how to format that nicely).

r.name sum(b.size_in_mb) tags \
r1            1000                        <List of tags> \
r1            100                          <List of tags> \
r2            1000                        <List of tags>


which is not the expected result. 
I want to sum the unique blobs per repository, so I am not sure what the goal of the collect is. 
I tried to play with the `WITH` statement but had no luck so far.

Comment: I think I got it, Michael, if you could comment on performance & style, that would be great:

`MATCH(r:Repository)<--(t:Tag)<--(b:Blob) with r, collect(distinct b) as distinctBlobs
RETURN r.name,  reduce(totalSum = 0, n IN distinctBlobs | totalSum + n.size_in_mb) as size_sum`